# Correct workflow in Xcode to avoid error: duplicate symbols for Architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c, xcode, compilation, linker

### Background

Hi, I am learning C++ and new to Xcode. I keep running into the error said in the title and not sure how to fix it. I wonder if learning the correct workflow in Xcode will help me avoid the problem.

Here is my directory:

### [image: Directory]

What I have here is:

Under project **signal**, I firstly created a group named
**signalMean**, which has some files and it compiles just fine. Then I simply created another group named **signalVariance** under **signal**, copied the exact same files from **signalMean** to this new group. After I added new functions to the main.cpp file and renamed it **signalVariance.cpp**, I kept getting duplicated symbols error when I tried to compile.

### Code

```cpp
// waveforms.h
extern double InputSignal_f32_1kHz_15kHz[320];
```

```cpp
// waveforms.cpp
#include "waveforms.h"
double InputSignal_f32_1kHz_15kHz[320] =
{+0.0000000000f, +0.5924659585f, -0.0947343455f,...}
```

```cpp
// signalMean.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "waveforms.h"
#define SIG_LENGTH 320

double calc_signal_mean(double *sig_src_arr, int sig_length);
double signal_mean;

int main() {
    //code
}
double calc_signal_mean(double *sig_src_arr, int sig_length) {
    //code
}
```

### Error

```
duplicate symbol _InputSignal_f32_1kHz_15kHz in:
    .../x86_64/waveforms-c8eb105c3a214768b4cffcf6a99ba09ec9961410b041f2905a2df7e9fe06655e.o
    .../x86_64/waveforms-c8eb105c3a214768b4cffcf6a99ba09e2eac5ae7a592aee13a84d551d65ef983.o
duplicate symbol _main in:
    .../x86_64/signalVariance.o
    .../x86_64/signalMean.o
duplicate symbol _signal_mean in:
    .../x86_64/signalVariance.o
    .../x86_64/signalMean.o
duplicate symbol __Z16calc_signal_meanPdi in:
    .../x86_64/signalVariance.o
    .../x86_64/signalMean.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

### Question

What should be the correct workflow in Xcode to avoid this issus if I want to keep building up the project from the previously written code like this? Each group will represent a different topic/function but they share code from each other and it makes sense to put them under the same project, e.g. **signal**.

I am sorry that this is a lengthy question. I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing Xcode *groups* and Xcode *targets*.

Groups are a method of organizing source code within your project (they also create folders in the filesystem), however, crucially to your issue, all the source code is compiled into the same target executable.

I think what you want to do is create multiple targets within the project and this allows you to define which of the source code files belongs to which of the targets.  See [this Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/WorkingwithTargets.html) on working with targets.

If you didn't realize, you cannot have multiple copies of the same *symbol* (method or variable) within a single executable unit (executable or dylib).

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you so much